# Magento 2 Product detail page show content without Tabs

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2, products, tabs

I want to show content without tabs on product detail page.  Magento shows description and reviews in tab on product detail page.

Is there any way we can remove the tab and show content vertically?

just like amazon: [image]

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if you have any issue

Comment: Check my answer. Update me if you have any issues.

Answer (score 3):

First remove description and review tabs from

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="product.info.description" remove="true" />
```

Now you can show description, more information, review.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.atributes.block" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-atributes-blocks" after="product.info.details">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description.full" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">Description</argument>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>

            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.description" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Don't forget to flush the cache

Comment: I placed same code which removes the tabs but doesn't add the description and reviews vertically without tabs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code in your module **catalog_product_view.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.overview" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.attributes" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.description" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```